# where clause with timezones

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm writing a where clause for a linq-to-sql query. Let's say a column name is AppointTime which is stored in GMT timezone. The query I'm writing is dynamic and the UI allows the user to select the appointments set today, yesterday, 2 days ago, 3, 5, 10, 30, 60, 90 days ago.

I have the user's timezone in a decimal (ie -9.0 for US PST time).

What's the best way to write the where clause so that the user who wants to see the appointments he set 2 days ago comes up in the query's result set.

Comment: Could you provide the schema for your table?

Comment: The table contains a column AppointSetDateTime that's the time at which the appointment was set. How do I retrieve all the appointments that were set 3 days ago for example. I have a decimal that's passed to the function that contains the timezone of the user (ie TheUserZone = -9.00)

Comment: BTW, if you are using LINQ to SQL, then you should use the linq-to-sql tag, not linq. "linq" refers to all of the LINQ technologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
int days = 2; // set by UI?
var upcoming =
    from appointment in dc.Appointments
    where appointment.AppointTime.AddHours(userTZ) < DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(days)
          && appointment.AppointTime > DateTime.UtcNow 
    orderby appointment.AppointTime ascending
    select appointment;
```

I confess I'm not totally clear on exactly what info you're trying to get... but this should hopefully contain enough clues to write the query you need. Remember two things - `Addx()` functions on `DateTime` can take a negative value to subtract; and times in the future are greater than times in the past, when comparing two `DateTimes`.

Comment: yes, AddHours was what I was looking for. Is there also a DecreaseHours because there's also a case where the user selects appoints NOT set in the last x days.

Comment: @frenchie ah, of course you don't want to show ones that have already passed. Let's add another condition to exclude appointment times that are less than now. (See update)